# Using Post method in Faceook Graph API

Tags: http, http-headers, api, facebook-graph

When I use graph API to post on a Facebook page it's not working, it responds with an ID and URL but instead it should be responding with a post id.

When I open the URL it gives this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "FdvAOg41htB"
   }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Facebook Graph API Explorer]

I'm providing the right access token but still it's not posting.

Comment: Do you know whether it is a short-lived (1-2 hours) or long-lived (60 days) token?

Comment: I had a long-lived page access token

Comment: @ashu Did you find the answer to this?